# Can you style individual letters within an input button's value?

Tags: button, input, styles, field

I would like to style each letter of the word SEND separately. I can't insert HTML into the value field, and I would prefer not to use an image.

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" />
```

I simply would like each letter to be a different color. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I found a tutorial on how to replace the button with a JavaScript text link. But as the tutorial states, the problem, then, is whether the end user has disabled JavaScript in their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lettering.js (http://letteringjs.com/)

It allows you to style each letter according to the CSS specification which isn't fully implemented in browsers.

Check http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx for example, e.g.

And in addition, use `button` instead of `input`:

```
<button type="submit">SEND</button>

button::first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I created an ugly hack with HTML+CSS only by using `button` element with `span` elements: http://cssdeck.com/labs/apkycgyi

```
<button type="submit">
  <span>S</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>D</span>
</button>

button {
  font-size: 0px;
}

button > span {
  font-size: 16px;
}

button span:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}

button span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}

button span:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: green;
}

button span:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works perfectly in Safari. I'm not sure about other browsers, but I think nth-of-type is widely recognized.